# Price Change History based on Product , Date and location level

Tags: sql

I need a SQL query that shows me price change history on locate, product and date bases.

Same like below screenshot.

[image]

and my table data is

[image]

Comment: Is this homework?https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. [Include screen shots on posts is dicouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Also, your post should include a question also what did you tried to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your RDBMS and its version, you may be able to use window function LAG, that gives you access to the previous row in a group, like :

```
SELECT
    location,
    product,
    date,
    price - LAG(price) OVER (PARTITION BY location, product ORDER BY date) change 
FROM mytable
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, i my issue has been solved by mentioned above query .

Answer (score 0):

Or with a subquery:

```
SELECT  price- (
        SELECT  TOP 1 price
        FROM   mytable m2
        WHERE  m2.location = m1.location and m2.product = m1.product and  m2.date< m1.date
        ORDER BY 
          date
        )
FROM mytable m1
```